# Can't get the stack trace using asyncio.ensure_future()

Tags: python, stack-trace, python-asyncio

This is what I tried:

```
>>> import asyncio
>>> @asyncio.coroutine
... def f():
...   print("RUN")
...   raise Exception("ciao")
... 
>>> asyncio.ensure_future(f())
<Task pending coro=<coro() running at /usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/coroutines.py:139>>
>>> loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
>>> loop.run_forever()
RUN
```

and the stack trace is not retrieved. If I run the coroutine with `asyncio.run_until_complete(f())` there's no problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to wait for the result of the coroutine somewhere, and the exception will be raised in that context.  All coroutines need to be "awaited"; `asyncio.run_until_complete()` will do that implicitly for you, but `run_forever()` can't, since it is supposed to run, well, forever.  Here's an example how you can see the exception (using Python 3.5 syntax):

```
>>> import asyncio
>>> import traceback
>>> async def f():
...     raise Exception("Viva la revolución!")
... 
>>> task_f = asyncio.ensure_future(f())
>>> async def g():
...     try:
...         await task_f
...     except Exception:
...         traceback.print_exc()
...         
>>> task_g = asyncio.ensure_future(g())
>>> asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-0d9e3c563e35>", line 3, in g
    await task_f
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 363, in __iter__
    return self.result()  # May raise too.
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "<ipython-input-3-928dc548dc3e>", line 2, in f
    raise Exception("Viva la revolución!")
Exception: Viva la revolución!
```